# How Can I use ExpressionVisitor to Change expression, adding more properties?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressionvisitor

I have a expression with two properties and, I need changing this expression at runtime to adding more items.

```
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            var query1 = db.product.Select(s => new ProductViewModel
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                Name = s.Name
            });

            // Here I need pass this query to a ExpressionVisitor.
        }
    }
```

After to pass the query1 to visitor, I hope that return to me a expression:

```
s => new ProductViewModel { Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name, BarCode = s.BarCode }
```

When the `BarCode` result, need return a default value, for exemple: `string.Empty`

How I can do it? I searched any examples on the internet, but I found nothing.

Comment: Why don't you make `BarCode` in `ProductViewModel` return `string.Empty` if it's null? Or assign `BarCode = s.BarCode ?? string.Empty`? It sounds like overengineering to use expressions for this.

Comment: I don't have access to the query1, because this I need changed. This code is a example

Comment: As @GertArnold mentioned, you should not need expression visitors for something like this. Just do the coalescing null assignment. If you do not have access to the `query1` as you say in your comment, you also cannot visit its expression. Your only other option then is to override the `BarCode` property in `ProductViewModel` to return "string.Empty" in case it's backing field is `null`, or do another projection of the result where you "fix this up".